# SQL Server Collation Inheritence

Tags: sql-server, collation

I've installed Umbraco into my ASP.NET MVC project and in installation asked for database information and generated catalog successfully.

I'm using a shared server which has a instance level collation that `Turkish_CI_AS`. While I tried some configuration I've encountered an error:

[In Umbraco, while tried to listing users the exception I've encountered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePwyg.png)

And so I've listed table's collation settings so I've discovered except `nvarchar` / `varchar` columns, all the columns' collations are NULL.

So in `umbracoUsers` (which is the users' table has a column 'id')

[Information of users' table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyekz.png)

I've also inspected Umbraco DB generator script via their source codes and there is no word like 'collation' in all scripts.

How to alter ALL column collations which are NULL to instance default collation?

Any ideas will be appreciated. Please do not hesitate :)

Regards.

Comment: Collation is **only** applicable to string columns - the collations for `datetime` or `int` columns are NULL, because **a collation makes NO SENSE for those types of columns**

Comment: but in Umbraco framework some queries with where clauses includes these INT columns and some queries with "id" and others with "Id" so that causes a problem. But nvarchar columns such as userName can be queried like "username" or "UserName". I need this flexibility. Just because Umbraco uses silly queries that changes action to action.

Comment: An `INT` column in SQL Server ***cannot*** have a collation.

Comment: So how do I solve this issue ? How can I make integer column names case insensitive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround this issue. For some reason I don't know but if you define instance / database level collation Turkish_CI_AS, this corrupt column name case-insensitivity. If you really have to use Turkish_CI_AS as collation (just like me) create database with this collation (so let the tables be with this collation) then alter DATABASE's collation with Latin1_General_100_CI_AS. (maybe other collation will also work)

This workaround provides that tables' collations are still Turkish_CI_AS and column-name based case sensitivity problem will be solved.

Thanks for your answers.